# Downloadhandler() downloads a file with only the column names of the actual dataframe inRShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I use the data below:

```
Database<-c("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","DCH","DCH","LDP")
Organism<-c("Human","Human","Human","Human","Human","Human","Mouse","Rat","Human")
Unique_Drugs<-c(12672,5130,1425,3090,6100,2019,250,736,1182)
Unique_Targets<-c(3987,2175,842,2308,2413,1441,198,327,702)
Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug<-c("5.87 ± 6.72","2.60 ± 6.87","2.28 ± 3.76","3.29 ± 5.03","3.60 ± 5.21","6.28 ± 14.29"
                             ,"1.92 ± 1.83"
                             ,"4.11 ± 5.32"
                             ,"4.27 ± 8.25"
)
Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target<-c("11.63 ± 15.59",
                             "12.52 ± 23.93",
                             "10.71 ± 8.37",
                             "12.98 ± 17.57",
                             "23.44 ± 25.65",
                             "13.87 ± 34.23",
                             "8.20 ± 18.44",
                             "14.82 ± 9.36",
                             "17.43 ± 9.34"
)
Unique_Drug_Target_Associations<-c(
45276,
14598,
3599,
12439,
23048,
13872,
594,
2876,
3915)

db<-data.frame(Database,Organism,Unique_Drugs,Unique_Targets,Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target,Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug, Unique_Drug_Target_Associations)
```

to create this working shiny app. The issue is that while (when opened in browser) the files are created and downloaded correctly they are empty or to be precise they include only the column names. As you can see from the datatable the dynamic dataframe is updated nicely. May it be a miss-communication between the reactive dataframe and the `downloadhandler()` or a bug inside the `downloadhandler()`?

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Stats Table"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("dbase"),
    tags$hr(),
    uiOutput("stats"),
    tags$hr(),
    h4(strong("Download Data in Table")),
    textInput("filename","Specify Filename"),
    #Added .json in the list
    selectInput("extension","File Format", choices = c("txt","csv","tsv","json")),

    column(1, align="center",
           # Style font family as well in addition to background and font color
           tags$style(type="text/css", "#downloadData {background-color:white;color: black;font-family: Arial}"),
           downloadButton("downloadData", "Download",class = "butt1"),
           tags$style(type='text/css', "#downloadData { vertical-align: middle;}")
    ) 

  ),
  dashboardBody(
    DTOutput('tbl')
  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) { 
  #Create the static dataframe below

  Database<-c("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","DCH","DCH","LDP")
  Organism<-c("Human","Human","Human","Human","Human","Human","Mouse","Rat","Human")
  Unique_Drugs<-c(12672,5130,1425,3090,6100,2019,250,736,1182)
  Unique_Targets<-c(3987,2175,842,2308,2413,1441,198,327,702)
  Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug<-c("5.87 ± 6.72","2.60 ± 6.87","2.28 ± 3.76","3.29 ± 5.03","3.60 ± 5.21","6.28 ± 14.29"
                               ,"1.92 ± 1.83"
                               ,"4.11 ± 5.32"
                               ,"4.27 ± 8.25"
  )
  Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target<-c("11.63 ± 15.59",
                               "12.52 ± 23.93",
                               "10.71 ± 8.37",
                               "12.98 ± 17.57",
                               "23.44 ± 25.65",
                               "13.87 ± 34.23",
                               "8.20 ± 18.44",
                               "14.82 ± 9.36",
                               "17.43 ± 9.34"
  )
  Unique_Drug_Target_Associations<-c(
    45276,
    14598,
    3599,
    12439,
    23048,
    13872,
    594,
    2876,
    3915)

  db<-data.frame(Database,Organism,Unique_Drugs,Unique_Targets,Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target,Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug, Unique_Drug_Target_Associations)

  #Create the databases checkbox group
  output$dbase<-renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("base", label = "Specify dataset(s)",
                       choices = list("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","LDP"),
                       selected = c("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","LDP")
    )
  })
  #Create the stats check box group
  output$stats<-renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("sta", label = "Specify statistic(s)",
                       choices = list("# Unique Drugs"="Unique_Drugs",
                                      "# Unique Targets"="Unique_Targets",
                                      "# of Drugs per Target"="Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target",
                                      "# of Targets per Drug"="Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug",
                                      "# Unique Drug-Target Associations"="Unique_Drug_Target_Associations"
                       ),
                       selected = c("Unique_Drugs","Unique_Targets","Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target","Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug","Unique_Drug_Target_Associations")
    )
  })
  #Subset the data based on user choices
  df_subset <- reactive({
    #By database
    a <- subset(db, Database %in% input$base)
    #By stats
    keeps <- c("Database","Organism",input$sta)

    # assigning the subset of db to tmp
    tmp <- a[ , which(names(a) %in% keeps)]

    # returning tmp
    return(tmp)

  })


  #Download files with quotes or not depending on the quote=input$quotes which has value TRUE or FALSE.
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename, input$extension, sep = ".")
    },

    # This function should write data to a file given to it by
    # the argument 'file'.
    content = function(file) {
      sep <- switch(input$extension,"txt"=",", "csv" = ",", "tsv" = "\t","json"=",")
      # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
      write.table(data.frame(df_subset())[input[["table_rows_all"]],], file, sep = sep,
                  row.names = FALSE) 

    }

  )

  output$tbl = renderDT(
    df_subset(), options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),selection = list(target = 'row+column')
  )



  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why but I had to remove `[input[["table_rows_all"]],]`